# rubygems.org timeout issue from command line -- SSL issue?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, rubygems, bundler

I haven't needed to use Linux in years, but now I am creating a linux machine so I can run Ruby on Rails.  I am using Ubuntu 18.04.  I thought I had everything loaded up and was trying to create my first Rails project but I got an error during:

```
run bundle install --local
Traceback (most recent call last):
    19: from /usr/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    18: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    17: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    16: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    14: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    13: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
    11: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    10: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
     9: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
     8: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
     7: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
     6: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
     5: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
     4: from (eval):1:in `run_bundle'
     3: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/generators/app_base.rb:351:in `run_bundle'
     2: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/generators/app_base.rb:335:in `bundle_command'
     1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
chris@linuxbox:~/Sites$
```

After digging into the problem, I found I am having a communication issue with gem. I can't communicate with rubygems.org from the command line! Everything I try seems to timeout, but I have no problem hitting rubygems.org from a browser.

I tried to install bundler with, but got this (after a long wait):

```
chris@linuxbox:~/Sites$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
chris@linuxbox:~/Sites$
```

I did some more digging and am wondering if I am having a OpenSSL issue. Here is the output from an eval statement:

```
chris@linuxbox:~/Sites$ ruby -ropen-uri -e 'eval open("https://git.io/vQhWq").read'
Here's your Ruby and OpenSSL environment:

Ruby:           2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
RubyGems:       2.7.7
Bundler:        1.16.2
Compiled with:  OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
Loaded version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
SSL_CERT_FILE:  /usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem
SSL_CERT_DIR:   /usr/lib/ssl/certs

With that out of the way, let's see if you can connect to rubygems.org...

Bundler connection to rubygems.org:       failed  ❌  (execution expired)
RubyGems connection to rubygems.org:      failed  ❌  (timed out (https://rubygems.org))
Ruby net/http connection to rubygems.org: failed  ❌

Unfortunately, this Ruby can't connect to rubygems.org. 
Even worse, we're not sure why. 

Here's the full error information:
Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired
  /home/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937:in `initialize'
  /home/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937:in `open'
  /home/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937:in `block in connect'
  /home/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'
  /home/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:935:in `connect'
  /home/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:920:in `do_start'
  /home/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:915:in `start'
  (eval):90:in `<main>'
  -e:1:in `eval'
  -e:1:in `<main>'

You might have more luck using Mislav's SSL doctor.rb script. You can get it here:
https://github.com/mislav/ssl-tools/blob/8b3dec4/doctor.rb
Read more about the script and how to use it in this blog post:
https://mislav.net/2013/07/ruby-openssl/
```

I downloaded and ran the doctor.rb script at the end of that output and this is what it said:

```
chris@linuxbox:~/Sites$ ruby doctor.rb 
/home/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby (2.5.1-p57)
OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017: /usr/lib/ssl
SSL_CERT_DIR=""
SSL_CERT_FILE=""

HEAD https://status.github.com:443
#<Net::HTTPGatewayTimeOut 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT readbody=true>
chris@linuxbox:~/Sites$
```

So am I right that I have a SSL issue?  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problems, almost exact outputs and commands you mention.

It was after a system update. I think problem was updating openssl to 1.1.1b but i'm not really sure as other software was updated too.

I tried things like

`openssl s_client -connect www.rubygems.com:443`

and

`wget  https://rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-2.7.7.tgz`

And i noticed it connects after like 2 minutes.

I casually watched wget output and appreciated that it worked when it switched to a ipv4 address.

So i searched how to prefer ipv4 over ipv6 on linux and seems that its possible on glibc based systems replacing the line:

`precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  10`

by

`precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100`

(10 to 100)

on

`/etc/gai.conf`

After that i could use ruby normally.

Hope it will help you.